# How to register a new user in wordpress site using REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I need to create a new user through my mobile app. So what i did i register a new route and call a callback function where i'll create a new user. But the problem is browser showing no routs found, another thing i used POST but still the data showing into the url.

Here is my code:

```
register_rest_route( 'base/v2','register/', array(
  'methods' => 'POST',
  'callback' => 'register_user',
) );
```

and the callback function is :

```
function register_user(){
   $username = $_POST['email'];
   $password = $_POST['password'];
   $confpassword = $_POST['confpassword'];

   if( $password === $confpassword ){
      if(strlen($password) >=6){
     $user_id = email_exists( $username );
     if ( !$user_id ) {
        $user_id = wp_create_user( $username, $password, $username );
     } else {
        $error = __('User already exists.  Password inherited.');
     }
  }
  else $error = __('Password can not be smaller then 6 letters');
   }else $error = __('Please password dosen\'t match');
  return $user_id;
}
```

Now how can i solve the problem ?

Comment: Well it works when i change the method as GET, but don't know why. Whereas the codex says to use POST method to create new post.

Comment: Did you solve it?  What language are you creating the app in?  I'm just starting down the road of making a user registration for a wp site in angularjs.

Comment: yeah, it's been solved. i am using android SDK for this.